# Out of the switch scope, how can I use the template variable which is defined in switch scope in C++

Tags: c++, templates

The code is as follows:

```
//template_test.h
enum SnType
{
    Sa,
    Sb,
    Sc
};
//main.cc
#include <iostream>
#include "template_test.h"
using namespace std;
template<SnType _Tsn>
class Test
{
    public:
        void print()
        {
            cout << "Type is " << _Tsn << endl;
        }
    
};
int main()
{
    SnType type = Sa;
    switch (type)
    {
        case Sa:
            Test<Sa> A;
            break;
        case Sb:
            Test<Sb> A;
            break;
        case Sc:
            Test<Sc> A;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    A.print();
    return 0;
}
```

when I run code , then the terminal shows the error: 'A' was not declared in this scope.

How can I use A out of the switch scop?
Out of the switch scope, how can I use the  template variable which is defined in switch scope in C++
Thanks a lot!

Comment: You can't. Types in c++ are static. You can't change type depending on a runtime value. Either you know the type, or you use some type-erasure like `std::variant` or a polymorphic class.

Comment: Why do you want to call `A.print()` out of the scope of `switch`? What is the purpose of calling `A.print()` when `SnType type` is set to `Sb`  and not  `Sa`, because in that case `A` would never be constructed?

Comment: Usually polymorphism is the solution. You could even get rid of the switch statement, letting runtime type resolution select the right print version (assuming it's a virtual member function of the base type).

Comment: You declare a variable in switch scope then call it outside, compiler don't know what is A variable. I think you should use inheritance with a super and 3 subclass A, B, C.

Comment: What did you intend with `Test<Sa>` ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust And `Test` expects an object of type `SnType` as template argument.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen: I am querying about the intent.

Comment: @YvesDaoust The above code is just a simplified version of my project

Comment: Mh, sorry to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I use A out of the switch scope?

You can't. It has ceased to exist.

Aside: All names that start with and underscore and are followed by a capital letter are reserved, `_Tsn` makes your program is ill-formed.

You'll have to do your type-dependant things within the switch, e.g.

```
#include <iostream>

enum SnType
{
    Sa,
    Sb,
    Sc
};

template<SnType Tsn>
class Test
{
    public:
        void print()
        {
            std::cout << "Type is " << Tsn << std::endl;
        }
    
};

template<SnType Tsn>
void testPrint()
{
    Test<Tsn>{}.print();
}

int main()
{
    SnType type = Sa;
    switch (type)
    {
        case Sa:
            testPrint<Sa>();
            break;
        case Sb:
            testPrint<Sb>();
            break;
        case Sc:
            testPrint<Sc>();
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```